# Bazel could not link a custom library

Tags: c++, linker-errors, bazel

When the constructor is defined in C++, cc_test could not link the library

in task.h file

```
class Task
  {
  public:
    Task(const std::string &name,
         std::function<void()> &&f,
         const absl::Time &run_time,
         bool repeat = false,
         const absl::Duration &interval = absl::Seconds(0))
        : name_(name), f_(f), repeat_(repeat), interval_(interval), run_time_(run_time)
    {
    }

    Task(const std::string &name,
         std::function<void()> &&f,
         const std::string &run_time,
         const std::string &time_zone,
         bool repeat = false,
         const absl::Duration &interval = absl::Seconds(0))
        : name_(name), f_(f), repeat_(repeat), interval_(interval)
    {
      run_time_ = util::ParseFromString(run_time, time_zone);
    }

    virtual ~Task() {}

    void Run();

    void IncrementRunTime();

    bool GetRepeat();

    absl::Time GetRunTime();

    std::string GetName();

  private:
    std::string name_;

    std::function<void()> f_;

    bool repeat_;

    absl::Duration interval_;

    absl::Time run_time_;
  };
```

in client.cpp file

```
shared_ptr<Task> begin_task =
                make_shared<Task>(
                    StrJoin({string("begin_task_for_client"), config_.name()}, "_"),
                    [this]()
                    {
                       // a bunch of work.
                    },
                    begin_time,
                    true,
                    Hours(24));

            Scheduler::Get().InsertTask(begin_task);
```

if I define the constructor in .h file, cc_test build is fine.

But if I define the constructor in .cpp file, cc_test build gives this error

```
gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc @bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/system/module/data/client/client_test-2.params
```

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox

```
bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_solib_k8/libsystem_Smodule_Sdata_Sclient_Slibclient.so: error: undefined reference to 'module::Task::Task(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, std::function<void ()>&&, absl::lts_20210324::Time const&, bool, absl::lts_20210324::Duration const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: How do you compile? Looks like you did not link the library.

Comment: I compile it with command 
     bazel test :client_test

In Bazel, we put the library in deps and it should auto link it.